# Анимированное меню

Tags: unity3d

Ребята помогите разобраться. Хочу сделать анимацию на картинки. Чтобы при нажатии кнопки, левая картинка сужалась в лево, а правая входила в камеру. Я сделал 2 canvas, и разместил картинки. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: сужалась в лево? это что значит? При хоть каком-то наглядном отображении того, что есть и что хочешь получить в итоге - всё выше описанное — непонятно

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите стандартный [туториал](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-transitions) как настраивать анимацию на кнопках (начиная с 2.46). Не надо ничего хитрого, просто сделайте также: делаете анимацию для кнопок  и привязываете ее к изменению состояний кнопок.